# 'Click to accept' checkbox to enable link

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox, hyperlink

I need to have a 'Click to Accept Terms' checkbox on my site (http://www.formulafast.co.uk/book-now.html), that enables a link to another page when checked.

So far I have adapted a script and html that has worked successfully (elsewhere on the internet) and works fine in JS fiddle (see http://jsfiddle.net/pjs53/hQJXW/104/) but as soon as I paste onto my page fails to work.

HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/><label for="check">I have read and accept the <a href="http://www.formulafast.co.uk/terms--conditions.html">Terms & Conditions</a></label></br></br>
```

The Javascript is in the jsfiddle above.

Worth mentioning that I'm using Weebly...and the html part is currently embedded as a snippet halfway down the page. The javascript is in the header section of this particular page. If anyone has a better suggestion please don't be shy.

I have a feeling it may be the placement of the code that may be causing it not to work, or I am missing a tag to link the two together...any ideas?

Comment: "As soon as I paste some code I found on the internet, it fails to work" Have you tried basic debugging?

Comment: Sorry - I haven't, where would I start?

Comment: I agree with the comments above, you very likely have a javascript error on your page which is causing your issues.

Comment: Did you use `document.ready` in your site?

Comment: Nightire - I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure, however there are other scripts running on the page just fine.

Jos Tokkellos - I've inspected the site through chrome and found the following: 'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function'. This is a symbol used in my script which is in the html header section...am I using the wrong symbols in the wrong places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the comments above, you actually forgot to include jQuery in your html, like this :

```
<script src="path_to_jquery_file"></script>
```

Your JSFiddle is using jQuery as a framework (look on the left), that's why it works but not your web page.

Comment: Thanks Ugo! So would the script reference need to be above or below the rest of the html for the checkbox?

Comment: Add the <script> tag that I mentioned just before in your page <head> tag, before your code.

Comment: Hmm...the script's uploaded and referenced in the page <head>, but still no luck. I got the 'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function ' in the console though...this is the first time I've used JS, how should the script start and end? It's starting with a $ symbol currently.

Comment: Got it! Turns out it needed jQuery(document).ready(function($) { on first line of js to get weebly to recognise the $. Also another closing }); to avoid any syntax errors. Thank you.